# Fitch Proof Help, Conclude ~B from ~(A > B)

Tags: proof, fitch

I'm in the process of learning fitch proofs and I've come across one I'm having trouble setting up.

Premise: ~(A > B)
Goal: (A & ~B)

In other words, it looks something like this:

```
1 | ~(A > B):PR
.
.
.
2 | A:... (I've achieved this much)
.
.
.
3 | ~B:?
4 |(A & ~B):&I 2,3
```

So far I've got logic for concluding A, but now I struggle to conclude ~B so that I can join the two.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: have you looked at a truth table for the material conditional? The answer should pretty  much fall right out from there

Comment: Then you're pretty close to the finish line since then after A suppose B then you immediately have A > B which is in direct contradiction your your 1st line PR, thus by ~I you arrive at ~B...

Comment: Thanks @DoubleKnot though I'm wondering how I can construct this A>B? I thought to construct an A>B I need a subproof above it with premise A and conclusion B?

Comment: You need a nested column after your line 2 and I'll leave it to you for its rule name...

Comment: Sure @DoubleKnot thanks for the help but I'm still a tad lost. I know I need a nested column after 2 but I don't know what it should be. In my mind if I want to construct a A>B, I need a subproof starting with A and ending with B, thus I can conclude it with A>B:subproof-line1-line2. I cant just simply assume B then write A>B because I havent concluded B yet starting from A.

Comment: Philosophically speaking as the ancient [shurangama sutra](http://www.cttbusa.org/shurangama/shurangama17.asp.html) hinted long ago: *To speak of the false is to reveal the true*, there's nothing wrong you can assume B after your A in a nested branching fashion as a first move and later arrive at a contradiction, then you can reveal the true...

Comment: Assume B and derive A > B and this gives you the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far I've got logic for concluding A, but now I struggle to conclude ~B so that I can join the two.

The subproofs for `A` and `~B` are *very similar* in outline, with just a slight variation in details.

In each you derive a contradiction of the premise, `~(A>B)`, to discharge their assumptions (of `~A` and `B` respectively) and derive their negations.

The deduction of that conditional, `A>B`, in each requires a Conditional Proof: Assume `A` so to derive `B`.  It is just that these derivations for `B` are different.

In the first do so by explosion of the contradictory assumptions (ex falso quodlibet).

In the second, just *reiterate* : `B` is true *under an assumption* of `B`.